# jQuery slideToggle & cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

I have a page which is dynamically generated and uses `slideToggle` to open and close the hierarchical `div`s etc no problem.  The only problem is, everytime I postback I have to generate the `div`s again and they lose their opened/closed state.  They are always generated with the same unique `id`s.

I would like to use the cookie plugin to remember the states when I call my `sltoggle` function and then when the page reloads expand all the same divs.  Heres what i've got so far...

```
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".toggle-hide").hide();
        //something in here about opening the divs in the cookie
    });

    function sltoggle(eID) 
    {
        $("div[id$='" + eID + "']").slideToggle(600);
        //I think the below code is okay - I copied it from a working example ^^
        var divState = ($("div[id$='" + eID + "']").css('display') == 'block') ? 1 : 0;
        $.cookie("divState", state)
     }
```

Comment: This heavily depends on how you structure your data in the cookie, but in case you just have a comma seperated list of active `div`s it could work sth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wCVAv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment explanations inline.

```
function slToggle(eID) {
   var $div = $("div[id$='" + eDI + "']");
   //Get value of cookie or empty string
   //Cookie is list of eIDs that should be visible
   var cooks = $.cookie("divState") || '';

   //Determine whether eID is already in the cookie
   var isin = $.inArray(eID, cooks.split(','));

   //TODO verify that .is("visible") check works during
   //toggle animation.  Otherwise, this code goes in the
   //toggle animation callback function
   if ($div.slideToggle(600).is(":visible")) {
      //Div is visible, but not in cookie
      if (!isin) {
         $.cookie("divState", cooks + (cooks ? ',' : '') + eID);
      }
   }
   else if (isin) {
      //Div not visible, but in cookie
      $.cookie("divState", cooks.replace(/(^|,)eID(,|$)/, ''));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i've implemented yours and m90s suggestions, for some reason its not saving the cookie so i'm just testing some basic stuff to make sure the latest version of jquery.cookie.js isn't fubared.

Comment: Seems it doesn't like the initial split (as theres no cookie yet).
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of null.  I guess I just need to do an if check on cooks before setting isin.

Comment: Hmm not sure how I edited your post @Explosion Pills, but there's the final working code. Marked yours as answer as the logic was spot on, just had to do some slight adjustments

Comment: @PeterLea great; I think SO answers should require a little bit of work on the part of the asker :)